# a test site using htaccess help needed

Tags: .htaccess

I have my website at root website .com/ I want to setup a folder like this website .com/us/

The folder /us/ is empty and when someone goes to it the folder shows the same content as what's in website .com but still staying on website .com/us/.

Here's the twist, if i wanted to show a different header.php or js or css file and this is loaded in to the domain website .com/us/, i need htaccess to use that instead of what's on website .com/. I will use the same directory structure.

Comment: Are you trying to build a multi language site? Then i18n is the term!

Comment: I am, we'll regional site and then using 
rel="alternate" hreflang="x"

To help Google serve the correct language or regional URL

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of many ways you can go about it. It's a crude example using mod_rewrite and php5 that hopefully gets you in the direction you want to go.

Using the example below navigating to should behave like the following

- http://example.com/ should show 'Content' with the header-default.php header
- http://example.com/us/ should show 'Content' with the header-us.php header
- http://example.com/some-other-directory/file.php should show 'Different Content in some other directory' with the header-default.php header
- http://example.com/us/some-other-directory/file.php should show 'Different Content in some other directory' with the header-us.php header

### .htaccess

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    php_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/header.php
    php_value auto_append_file  /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/footer.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^us/?$    /index\.php?tpl=us    [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
    RewriteRule ^us/(.*)$    /$1?tpl=us    [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

### /header.php

```
<?php 
$tpl = $_GET['tpl'];
if ($tpl === 'us') {
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header-us.php';
}
else {
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header-default.php';
}
?>
```

### /header-us.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>USA</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Welcome to the US section">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/us/style.css">
  <script src="/js/us/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

### /header-default.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome to index</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Welcome to the DEFAULT section">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

### /footer.php

```
<p>user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required</p>
</body>
</html>
```

### /index.php

```
Content
```

### /some-other-directory/file.php

```
Different Content in some other directory
```

Comment: Is there not a way for htaccess to say hey, if there's no file in /us/ then go to root and if there is a file in /us/ then use this and get the rest from root?

Comment: I know some developers have test sites where they have a url say /test/ and if they want to chnage a file to test they only load that file in to the test folder and the rest is pulled from the main site.

Comment: @William yes with the proper `RewriteCond` which I did one for you but I would kind of do what your referring to more with PHP. Using one catch all and then file/directory checking and inclusion.

Comment: thanks for the code which i tested here on a local machine. It bolts a query on to the url which we're keen to avoid. Is there a way to strip this out?

Comment: @William works fine for me, it must be something else you got going. Like a 301 redirect or some other code.

Comment: I did see one small error on my second rewrite but it should not be causing that error. I've editing the htaccess so it is now `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f`